# Java Json beautifying on save

Tags: java, json, syntax, gson

I am saving a player to a .json file like this:

```
public static void savePlayer(Player player) {
    final String username = player.getUsername();
    final byte[] json = new Gson().toJson(player).getBytes();
    final String path = "pack/players/" + username;

    try {
        Files.write(Paths.get(path + "/data.json"), json, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);   
        logger.info("Successfully SAVED player [username=%s]!", username);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and I am using this Eclipse JSON editor plugin to view the json file: https://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipsejsonedit/

However, when looking at the file it is all compressed in one line and not beautified.

The resulting one line of json code is printed like this (instead of beautified):

```
{"inventory":{"data":[null]},"equipment":{"data":[null]},"playerCredentials":{"username":"kay","password":"password"},"attribute":{}}
```

What can I do to beautify the code before saving it?

Comment: You need to set that setting with GsonBuilder.

Comment: @vandench Did not even know that class could format, what method do I use in the builder? I don't see any which accepts param String?

Comment: You use one of the builder methods to set the property, it’s called something like pretty print. Once you call build you get a configured Gson object that you can then use to generate json.

Comment: The function is `setPrettyPrinting()`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Gson you can use their prettyPrinting and create a new Gson obejct

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
```

And then create a String object from that

```
String output = gson.toJson(json);
```

If you use FileWriter you can simple use that string to write to a file.